# setInterval and clearInterval not workin together

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

So I have a setInterval and clearInterval fucntion to start and stop a counter respectively. The problem here is everytime i click the button, the state gets set to true and the timerfunction is triggered which starts the timer. Now clicking the timer again, the timer does not stop as the refreshIntervalId variable now has a value of undefined. Kindly help me on this please!

Here's my code:

```
  if (timer == true) {
    console.log("timer is playing");
    refreshIntervalID = setInterval(timerFunction, 1000);
    console.log(refreshIntervalID);
  }

  if (timer == false) {
    console.log(refreshIntervalID);
    clearInterval(refreshIntervalID);
  }
```

Here's the full code:

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { playToggle, reset } from "./actions/indexAction";

function Timer() {
  const timer = useSelector((state) => state.timer);
  const sessionLength = useSelector((state) => state.sessionLength);

  let minutes = sessionLength;
  let seconds = 60;
  var refreshIntervalID;

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  let resetClick = () => {
    return dispatch(reset());
  };

  let timerFunction = () => {
    if (timer == true) {
      seconds--;
      console.log(seconds);
    }
  };

  if (timer == "reset") {
    minutes = sessionLength;
    seconds = 60;
    console.log("Is Reset");
  }

  if (timer == true) {
    console.log("timer is playing");
    refreshIntervalID = setInterval(timerFunction, 1000);
    console.log(refreshIntervalID);
  }

  if (timer == false) {
    console.log(refreshIntervalID);
    clearInterval(refreshIntervalID);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Minutes: {minutes}</h1>
      <h1>Minutes: {seconds}</h1>
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => dispatch(playToggle())}>PLAY/PAUSE</button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button onClick={resetClick}>RESET</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Timer;
```

Comment: Where do you *declare* `refreshIntervalID`? You need to have it scoped so that the `clearTimer` call has access to it.

Comment: so the scope is present in a redux reducer. The problem is that when I try to give a state it is throwing a lot of errors. I shall upload the whole file for you to have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't fully relevant as the comment this was related to turned out to be not entirely accurate:

You absolutely don't want to be having side-effects within a redux reducer. Make the side-effects happen in the component instead. The reason is that reducers should be pure for the whole flux architecture to work properly. The only time there should be side-effects in a reducer is if you are using a middleware like [redux-loop](https://redux-loop.js.org/). Otherwise you can quickly get some very unmaintainable code.

If this is in a functional component, here's how I do it:

```
function(){
  useEffect(()=>{
    if (timer) {
      console.log("timer is playing");
      const refreshIntervalID = setInterval(timerFunction, 1000);
      console.log(refreshIntervalID);
      return ()=>{
        clearInterval(refreshIntervalID)
      }
    }
  },[timer])
}
```

You have to clear the interval within the useEffect hook

Edit: Add hopefully working code

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { playToggle } from './actions/indexAction';

function Timer() {
  const timer = useSelector((state) => state.timer);
  const sessionLength = useSelector((state) => state.sessionLength * 60); // session in seconds
  const [seconds, setSeconds] = useState(sessionLength);
  const [resetTimer, setResetTimer] = useState(0);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  let resetClick = () => {
    // Get a new value every time
    setSeconds(sessionLength);
    setResetTimer((value) => value + 1);
  };
  useEffect(()=>{
    // Set the timer to use the latest value when the session length changes.
    setSeconds(sessionLength)
  },[sessionLength])

  useEffect(() => {
    // Perform a side effect
    if (timer) {
      // Only run the timer when timer is truthy
      let timerFunction = () => {
        setSeconds((seconds) => seconds - 1);
      };
      console.log('timer is playing');
      const refreshIntervalID = setInterval(timerFunction, 1000);
      return () => {
        // Clean up timer before effect runs again (or on unmount)
        clearInterval(refreshIntervalID);
      };
    }
    // Restart timer whenever timer, sessionLength, or resetTimer changes
  }, [timer, resetTimer]);

  useEffect(() => {
    // If the timer has elapsed, stop the timer and reset.
    if (seconds <= 0) {
      dispatch(playToggle());
      setSeconds(sessionLength);
    }
  }, [seconds, dispatch, sessionLength]);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Minutes: {Math.floor(seconds / 60)}</h1>
      <h1>Minutes: {seconds % 60}</h1>
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => dispatch(playToggle())}>PLAY/PAUSE</button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button onClick={resetClick}>RESET</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Timer;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am still confused as to how I should implement the function in the code. I am a beginner here and it would be great if you can help me with the thing. I have attached my full code for your reference.

Comment: I've refactored your code and added some basic comments to it. Hopefully this helps! Let me know if you have any issues.

Comment: Thanks for the code. Its throwing an error saying usestate and useEffect is not defined.

Comment: You have to import them from React. For reference, the first line in the updated code.

Comment: Sorry about that, it was a typo. seconds( should've been setSeconds( at that line. I updated it in the answer. If there are any more things like that, go ahead and set up a chat for us to use instead of a comments thread.

Comment: Hi, Thanks a ton for your help! Works perfect. Now, all I have to do is understand the code thoroughly. I was just close to giving up but your solution has got me right back on track. So thanks once again!